# convert sql-server *.mdf file into sqlite file

Tags: sqlite, mdf

Just wondering if it is possible to convert sql-server *.mdf file into sqlite file ?

Answer (score 10):

There's a C# utility to automatically do the conversion from SQL Server DB to SQLite DB on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/convsqlservertosqlite.aspx)

Comment: You should move your code to codeplex or google code. codeproject is very unfriendly.

Comment: good thing this post came up when I searched for a similar tool... just would like to ask @bruce-mcleod how codeproject is becoming unfriendly... :)

Comment: How to set Sql Server address my `set` button is disabled

Answer (score 2):

DBConvert for SQLite and MS SQL is a dependable bi-directional database converter which enables you to migrate data from SQLite to MS SQL server and from MS SQL to SQLite. DBConvert features: Unicode Support, Primary keys and Indexes conversion, Interactive multilingual (GUI) mode/command line mode, preverification of possible conversion errors, the ability to use MS SQL Dump if you don't have a direct access to MS SQL server, etc.

http://www.itshareware.com/prodview-code_65203--download-dbconvert-for-sqlite-and-mssql.htm

Couldnt find a free one for you!