# Forms Authentication with sqlite

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sqlite, forms-authentication, data-migration

I have an ASP MVC-application that uses a SQL server express for and Forms authentication. The server I'm using does not have enough memory to run SQL Server express stably and I was thinking about migrating to SQLite instead.

Is it possible to just migrate the existing aspnetdb-database from SQL Server to SQLite so that all my user accounts will be kept?

Answer (score 1):

These shall help you perform such task:

1. [SQLite Converter Tools](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ConverterTools)
2. [SQL Maestro (This one's not free though)](http://www.sqlmaestro.com/products/sqlite/datawizard/)
3. [A good migrating tool project from Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/convsqlservertosqlite.aspx)
4. [SO: convert sql-server *.mdf file into sqlite file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959711/convert-sql-server-mdf-file-into-sqlite-file)

So, I guess that if such tools exist, it will then be possible to keep your data.

For security, perform a backup from your DB first!