# Bulk Conversion of Large SQL Databases (100 GB stored in 10 files (100 tables/file) to SQLite

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite

I am converting a large SQL database (100GB stored in 10 files, with 100 tables per file) to SQLite. Right now, I am using the CodeProject C# utility, as suggested in another thread ([convert sql-server *.mdf file into sqlite file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959711/convert-sql-server-mdf-file-into-sqlite-file)). However, this approach is not entirely satisfactory for two reasons:

1. The conversion process usually stops abruptly when converting one of my files. Then I have to go in and check which tables were successfully converted or not.
2. I could manually convert 10 tables at a time; but this requires 100 repetitions and my constant presence in front of my computer.

Thank you so much for your kind regards!

Comment: Since the CodeProject project gives you the source, have you considered modifying that source to loop through things, so you can do 10 at a time but don't have to sit there in person?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible a "transaction log" is being created.   This is the log used to rollback changes if something goes wrong.  Since your job is so large, this log file can grow too large and the process will fail.

Try this:

1)  Back up the data.

2)  Turn off the log with this:  `PRAGMA database.journal_mode = OFF;`

Caveat:  I've never tried this with SqlLite but other databases work in a similar fashion.