# Use SQL Server database in ASP.Net without server installation?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Is it possible to use a SQL Server database, i.e. a `.mdf` file, without having to install SQL Server (Express)?

Comment: You could convert it to SQLite: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/959711/convert-sql-server-mdf-file-into-sqlite-file as that is embeddable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No** you cannot use `.mdf` file without installing SQL Server on your system. However, there are some open source projects which you might be interested to look in like [OrcaMDF](https://github.com/improvedk/OrcaMDF#readme) which you can use to read the SQL server data files without the usage of SQL Server installation.